# Android Loader Application Not Responding

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, loader

I'm getting an ANR in my android application and i can't find the problem. Using Strict Mode i get this exception:

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=2 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1107)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:835)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getCount(CursorWrapper.java:57)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getCount(CursorAdapter.java:202)
        at com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.BaseAdapterDecorator.getCount(BaseAdapterDecorator.java:69)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:801)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
        at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
        at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver.onChanged(CursorAdapter.java:473)
        at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.requery(AbstractCursor.java:137)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:225)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.onContentChanged(CursorAdapter.java:449)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver.onChange(CursorAdapter.java:465)
        at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
        at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The application does the following:

1. Start an Intent Service and grabs some feeds.
2. Persist the feeds to a DB through a content provider.
3. The fragment, has a loader that gets notified when the write happens
4. The loader reads the new data, passes it to a cursor adapter and shows it.

However when the read happens, sometimes i get an ANR, from what i understand from the stack trace, the cursor requery the database, and i get an ANR if it takes too long, however i though Loaders did the operations async. I don't know how to solve this problem.

I initialize the adapter with the "auto-query" flag set to false it that matters.

Using android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the database transactions on a background thread. You're doing it on the main thread, hence the strict mode error. You could use an AsyncTask and do the transaction in the doInBackground() method.

Comment: Not sure if i understand you, doesn't the Cursor Loader executes the queries async ?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have any other transactions which might not run on a background thread ?

Comment: Pretty sure i don't have any other transactions, maybe i need to debug it with other tool to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cursor adapter, make sure that you don't pass autoRequery flag to it in the constructor. If you pass true, Cursor.requery() will be called by the adapter, what is wrong, because this call will be triggered in UI thread. Also in a parallel thread, CursorLoader will be selecting data. So, if you will remove autoRequery flag from the CursorAdapter, the problem shuld gone. I dnon't know why this constructor wasn't deprecated but we have what we have.